# unix:I am not a sudo user \usr\ucb\ps auxwww

Tags: unix, ps

I am not a sudo user
sudo \usr\ucb\ps auxwww is giving me an error message restricted command or requested user not allowed.

I am using auxwww to get the complete line of the process.

It would be great if anyone can help me in this.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Root user has to make changes to the following:

- cd /etc/sudoers

Like below and you will be able to execute all the command using `sudo`.

```
%group  ALL=(ALL)   ALL
```